# Cut off a specific part in a String

Tags: java

For examples, I have:

```
String s = "{\"ABC\"}:Mycontent{\"123\"}";
```

I only want to get the Mycontent{"123"} part and this part can be changed dynamically. Can anybody please show me how to do it (Fast performance)?

Comment: May the "ABC" part contain colons (in that case, use regexp), or is value you want after the first colon always (in that case, use the indexOf answer below)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split method inside string can split a string around matches of regular expression so you can use this method. 
You can also use subsequence method if the position of the string you want is always the same.
Also you can use the substring method.
Many ways. Personal favorite is substring

```
str2=str.substring(begin, [end])
```

I put [] around end because it is not necessary. If you do not put an end index the substring will continue until the end of the string. Both indexes must be integers. Also this method returns a string.

If the size of the number changes dynamically aswell (e.g. 123 turns to 4567) you can solve this by not using an end index then using a find function and finding the character that comes after the last digit in your string (I suppose this does not change) and then replacing that character (using a replace method) with a \0 so the string ends there.

All the methods I have mentioned and there explanations can be found in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: It's helpful to include links to documentation or examples, so it's clearer what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Using indexOf on the string, you can find the occurrence of ':' and get the substring from there as follows:

```
s.substring(s.indexOf(':') + 1)
```

If this is a structured output from an upstream system, you should look for standard way to interpret it (at first look, it appeared like JSON which means you should use a JSON parser. But it seems to be something else, you would know better about the source of this input).

Comment: This is not a JSON object. And it would be easier to skip the indexOf if you know the string will always have the same format: `s.substring(8)`

Comment: Please, this is not a Json String, it only looks like JSON, so there is no / , and as I said, it can contain everything in Mycontent thus using : to split isnot a good way

Comment: Right, this doesn't seem to be JSON. "ABC" may not be a constant, I guess, though OP didn't speak about this portion of the string.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it not being JSON; JSON simply doesn't have anything even close to `{"ABC"}:somestring{"XYZ"}`

Comment: @Aptos, do you mean to say the the first portion `{"ABC"}` can also potentially contain colons? If not, indexOf would only return the index of the first colon, and should address your case, right?

Comment: @Aptos, Can you depend on the string you want to split off always being at index 8? If so, you can use my substring example. In addition, note that Vikdor's solution will get the index of the very first colon; if there are colons further along in Mycontent, they won't matter.

Comment: thank guys, but you forgot about this part Mycontent{\"123\"}" , I only need to get Mycontent{\"123\"}

Comment: @Aptos, I think we are not on the same page. Could you please update your question two input and expected output and provide this for two different strings that you might encounter? That would clarify what you mean by your previous statement.

Comment: @Aptos, that is precisely what substring does; it extracts a part of a string, starting at a given index, and returns just that part as a new string. For the example you've given, our solutions will return the string "Mycontent{\"123\"}"